# f is uniformly continuous then is indefinite integral of some $g \in R(a, b)$

Tags: analysis, riemann-integration

I want to prove the following statement.

> If $f$ is uniformly continuous on the open interval $(a, b)$, then $f$ is an indefinite integral of some $g\in R(a, b)$.

The answer says that this statement is true, and I want to prove it. However, I don't know the sufficient and necessary conditions that would make some function an indefinite integral of some other function. If $f$ is differentiable, then taking $g(x)=\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$ would make it an indefinite integral of some other function, but uniformly continuous does not imply differentiable. How would I do this?

Comment: This statement is false.  You need a stronger property than uniform continuity called absolute continuity.

Comment: Ohh...Thanks. I was digging in the wrong place, no wonder it looked weird.

Comment: Absolute continuity provides only the existence of a Lebesgue integrable function, not a Riemann integrable function.  If you want a necessary and sufficient condition for the latter I can supply it, but I think all you need here is an example of a continuous function that is not an indefinite Riemann integral.   Take one that is not Lipschitz.

Comment: @JoshuaWoo  P.S.  It is not true that if f  is differentiable then it must be an indefinite integral in the Riemann sense, nor even the Lebesgue sense.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson I'm sorry I saw your comment late. Thanks for the counterexample. About the P.S, if $f$ is differentiable, then can't we say $f=\int_{a}^{x}f'(t)dt$, and conclude that $f$ is some indefinite integral of $g=f'$?

Comment: @JoshuaWoo Not for the Riemann integral. Not for the improper Riemann integral. Not for the Lebesgue integral. Yes for the Denjoy-Perron integral.  Derivatives are more complicated than a course in calculus would suggest.